# API Platform DTO Validator - Missing properties are no violation

Tags: symfony, validation, api-platform.com, symfony-validator

I have an API Platform DataTransformer that uses an injected ValidatorInterface to verify the JSON POST body of an incoming request. It is basically a copy of the example in the [docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/#validating-data-transfer-objects):

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTransformer;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Validator\ValidatorInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataTransformer\DataTransformerInterface;
use App\Entity\Ticket;
use App\DTO\TicketInput;

class InputDataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly ValidatorInterface $validator,
    ) {}

    /**
     * @param TicketInput $object
     */
    public function transform($object, string $to, array $context = []): Ticket
    {
        // Validation
        $this->validator->validate($object);

        $ticket = new Ticket($object->id, $object->content);
        return $ticket;
    }

    public function supportsTransformation($data, string $to, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return (Ticket::class === $to) && (($context['input']['class'] ?? null) === TicketInput::class);
    }
}
```

Via a ContextBuilder and the `supportsTransformation()` I ensure that the incoming `$object` is of type TicketInput. This class is as easy as that:

```
<?php

namespace App\DTO;

class TicketInput
{
    public int $id;
    public ?string $content;
}
```

What I am wondering about: The validator validates via the `TicketInput::class` that `$id` must be an integer and is not nullable. `$content` must be a string and is allowed to be null.

So these are **valid** inputs:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "content": null
},
{
    "id": 123,
    "content": "testtest"
}
```

And this is **invalid** and gets rejected (400 - Bad request):

```
{
    "id": null,
    "content": "foobar"
}
```

So far so good. But one of my unit tests uses this JSON as request body:

```
{
    "content": "foobar"
}
```

This broke my code as `$id` is a required value for the resulting `Ticket::class`.

I am pretty surprised that the last case was able to pass the validator, as I explicitly define the `$id` as (not nullable) class variable in `TicketInput::class`. One could argue that the validator is not obliged to validate properties that are *uninitialized* at time of validation (which is the case here, according to a `var_dump`) but nevertheless I am interested in how to define that this property is **mandatory** and has to be part of the JSON POST body.

The best what I could come up with was the Symfony Validation Constraint `#[Assert\NotBlank(allowNull: false)]` (see [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html)), which checks against `is_null()` and indirectly `isset()`, but I can't believe that this is the solution and I have to flag every single property like that (the actual `TicketInput::class` is way more huge and complex than this MWE).

Isn't there any validator config flag that tells it to assure the properties in a DTO are mandatory in a JSON body?

Every simple JSON Schema validator is capable of this and I am wondering why I don't find any hints for this either in the Symfony Docs nor the API Platform docs.